# How to get instantly update from the textfield?

Tags: java

I want to change the input in the textfield which will instantly update to the display, instead of press `ENTER` button to update it.

Here is my code.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MyProgram01 extends JFrame
{
    private JTextField text1;
    private JCheckBox check1;
    private JCheckBox check2;
    private String message;
    private JLabel label1;
    private JLabel label2;
    private Font font;

    public MyProgram01(String title)
    {
        super(title);
        check1 = new JCheckBox("Bold");
        check2 = new JCheckBox("Italics");

        label1 = new JLabel("Text : ");
        label2 = new JLabel("Style : ");
        message = "Good Morning...";
        text1 = new JTextField(message, 100);
        font = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 36);
        setBounds(0, 0, 600, 300);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(null);
        panel.setBounds(0, 0, 600, 120);
        panel.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        label1.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 36));
        label1.setBounds(15, 15, 100, 36);
        panel.add(label1);
        text1.setBounds(120, 15, 400, 36);
        panel.add(text1);

        label2.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 36));
        label2.setBounds(15, 65, 100, 36);
        panel.add(label2);
        check1.setBounds(120, 65, 100, 36);
        check2.setBounds(220, 65, 100, 36);
        panel.add(check1);
        panel.add(check2);

        check1.addActionListener(new CheckBoxListener());
        check2.addActionListener(new CheckBoxListener());
        text1.addActionListener(new TextFieldListener());

        setLayout(null);
        add(panel);
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);

        g.setFont(font);
        g.drawString(message, 15, 255);

    }
    private class CheckBoxListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if(check1.isSelected() && check2.isSelected())
            {
                font = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD + Font.ITALIC, 36);    
                repaint();
            }
            else if(check1.isSelected())
            {
                font = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 36);
                repaint();
            }
            else if(check2.isSelected())
            {
                font = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.ITALIC, 36);
                repaint();
            }
            else
            {
                font = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 36);
                repaint();
            }
        }
    }
    private class TextFieldListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            message = text1.getText();
            repaint();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new MyProgram01("My Program 01");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

How can I change the code to instantly update to the display?

EDIT :

It's work with the keyListener, but my program will only start display after second key is pressed.

For example, I key in `abc`, the program will start show `a` when I press `b`, and when I pressed `c`, it displays `ab` and `c` is missing, unless I press `ENTER`.

Here the part of the code :

```
text1.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter()
    {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
            {
                message = text1.getText();
                repaint();
            }
    });
```

Comment: Try with keyTyped(KeyEvent e) over keyPressed(KeyEvent e).

Comment: Do you means replace `keyPressed` to `keyTyped`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `KeyListener` to your textfield.
You can do that like this:

```
textField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
         message = textField.getText();
         repaint();
    }
});
```

**OR**

Add a `DocumentListener` to your textfield's `Document`.
You can do that like this:

```
private JFrame getFrame(){
    return this;
}
...

textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener(){

    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        message = textField.getText();
        getFrame().repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        message = textField.getText();
        getFrame().repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        // on change
    }

});
```

Comment: I recommend this answer over the KeyListener one. For KeyListeners, you have to implement all the methods whether you want to use them or not and it will clutter your code. Just remember to call super.keyPressed(e) when using the adapter.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using ActionListener for the class TextFieldListener, use KeyListener interface and use the keyTyped(KeyEvent e) method. When ever the event arises you can use getText() of texfield and repaint it.